# XAMPP How to restart the server

Tags: html, apache, xampp

I am new to web design, and I am using XAMPP for my website to test PHP and MySQL, I noticed that when I modify the index.html (HTML, CSS), I don't see the changes immediately when I open it from the browser localhost/webdesign/index.html. I often have to wait for more than 10 minutes to see the changes in localhost.

However, if I open it locally D:/xampp/htdocs/webdesign/index.html I can see the modification I made immediately.

I restarted the Apache server from the XAMPP control panel and still don't see the changes that I made. Anyone know how to fix this?

When I changes the picture files, I can see the modification I made in the source code in localhost/index.html, but the pictures are still the same, the files are not being updated.

What can I do to speed things up?

Comment: how's the speed of xampp? is it working normally to open up the pages or is it slow to load the page?

Comment: And make sure your files are inside WWW folder.

Comment: my xampp is really fast, where is WWW folder? Now the source code got updated, but the pictures are still the same.

Comment: Then it would be 'htdocs' folder on your system. Try another browser just for test.